# Calculating load experienced by pins in excavators

Tags: mechanical-engineering

I am trying to figure out a way to calculate the load on the various pins in an excavator and basically can't understand how. Can someone point me in the right direction. Is it just taking moment about the pin and taking the breakout force of the bucket as an eccentric load? Or is there more to it?

P.S. - I'm not sure what appropriate tags to use, so I'll edit the post if someone can let me know.

[Deformation in pins with different induction hardening](https://oaji.net/articles/2017/1992-1514529185.pdf)

[The paper I'm referring to](https://www.ijert.org/research/analysis-of-bucket-teeth-of-backhoe-excavator-loader-and-its-weight-optimization-IJERTV4IS050402.pdf)

Comment: Are the pins in single or double shear?

Comment: @SolarMike Double shear.

Comment: Google search: https://www.engineersedge.com/material_science/bolt_double_shear_calcs.htm Shows you the formulae and even further references.

Comment: Use rated cylinder force. Consider both actuation with hydraulics moving the cylinder, and static hold if there is a hydraulic lock position. Also consider the load when the maintenance/transport crutches are in place. Sometimes, the shock loads in transport position can exceed the actual operating loads. You really have to check the extremes of geometry and the the loads in all modes. Then you have to consider the grease bearing surface and what you want the interface to withstand. It's helpful if a grease gun can actually push grease into the joint when at rest :)

Answer (score 0):

I have used the figure from your link and looked at 3 pins. A,B,C.

Let's say the force coming from the excavator shovel digging the earth is 10k.lbs and the arm length from the shovel to pin B is 12ft. So our moment at the attachment to the tractor is $M=10k*12=120k.lbs.ft$

Assuming the distance between pin B and C is two feet, each of them undergoes shearing stress of

$$V_{B}= V_{c}=\frac{120k}{2}=60k.lbs$$
Pin B is receiving a shear directed to the right and pin C to left.

This, of course, needs to be multiplied by an appropriate factor of safety.

By inspection, we see that pin A at the end of the actuator gets the same shear as pin C.

## Edit

This is a very simplified version of the story, otherwise, we need to figure out the weight of the arm, the reaction of the fork, impact forces, and dynamic force due to the articulation of the levers. After @Phil Sweet comment.

'

[image: excavator]

Comment: Don't forget the 10,000 pounds of earth force on the bucket which has to find it's way through to the tractor.